# Custom data types in Facelets JSF 2 Expression Language

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets, el

How to display a custom property using facelet expression language?

For example:

```
<h:outputText value="#{contact.customTypeProperty}" />
```

where customTypeProperty is of type CustomClass, and I want to display the String returned by its toString()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should already be the default behaviour. You don't need to change anything on the given code example, assuming that the `toString()` method is properly implemented on the `CustomClass`. However, if it returns HTML, you'd need to add `escape="false"` to the output text to prevent JSF from auto-escaping it (which it does in order to prevent XSS attacks on user-controlled input):

```
<h:outputText value="#{contact.customTypeProperty}" escape="false" />
```

This is however not necessarily the best practice. You should control the presentation in the view side, not in a `toString()` in the model side. For example, assuming that `CustomClass` has in turn two properties `foo` and `bar` and you'd like to present it in a table:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2">
    <h:outputText value="Foo" />
    <h:outputText value="#{contact.customTypeProperty.foo}" />

    <h:outputText value="Bar" />
    <h:outputText value="#{contact.customTypeProperty.bar}" />
</h:panelGrid>
```

If you did this to avoid code repetition, then you should actually be using an include file or a tag file. See also [When to use <ui:include>, tag files, composite components and/or custom components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822000/when-to-use-uiinclude-tag-files-composite-components-and-or-custom-componen)

Comment: Thanks BalusC, somehow the Object's toString is called. Although it is correctly overridden in CustomClass.

Comment: Put `@Override` annotation on the `toString()` method to make sure that you didn't make any typos of changes in method signature. It has to be `public String toString() {}` without arguments and throws.

Comment: Override notation is there, I guess the issue is unrelated to JSF. The wsimport doesn't generate toString. So the problem lies somewhere there.